# Kotlin on Android - is there a minimum API level requirement?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am seriously considering using Kotlin on a greenfield Android project, but am concerned about knock-on implications, the most significant of which is a minimum required API level.

On other platforms, new languages have required a certain OS version (e.g. Swift requiring iOS 7) and I wondered whether there were similar requirements here?

I've been searching through various Kotlin/Android FAQs and Stackoverflow but have not been able to find this information.

Comment: No, Kotlin compile to Java byte code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No. There's no such requirement for the API level as these two are not directly related. Anyway, see [official FAQ](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/faq.html)

> Which versions of Android does Kotlin support?
>
> All of them! Kotlin is compatible with JDK 6, so apps with Kotlin
>   safely run on older Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin 1.5 deprecates java 6, and only supports java 8 going forward. So if you are using Kotlin ~1.4 you will have 0 compatability issues.

Not 100% sure which API level becomes the minimum with 1.5+, maybe someone else could shed more light or correct me.