# Kotlin Monads and Lambda in Android

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

So I understood that Java 8 features such as Lambdas or Streams are only available for API level 24+ in Android.

What about lambdas and monads in Kotlin ? Are they also only available after level 24, or are they available for any API level (since the introduction of Kotlin) ?

Since they are handled very differently internally as far as I know, I'm curious to know if this is the case.

Comment: Any API level that Kotlin supports can use lambdas.

Comment: So if I understand correctly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539682/5666171), I can use lambdas and monads from within Kotlin for every API level ?

Comment: yes. I can tell from you personal experience that they work at least down to 16.

Comment: What are Kotlin monads?

Comment: I mean methods like List.map or List.sortedBy which are only available for Kotlin collections

Comment: Thanks @TheWanderer, you can convert your reply to an answer, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin's lambdas and extension functions (what you're calling monads) are supported on API 16+, and should be supported on API 14+ too. When Kotlin is compiled to Java, it converts lambdas to normal Java statements (sort of, it's a mess if you try decompiling to Java). I'm not entirely sure how extension functions work, but they're converted as well.

In any case, Android Studio should tell you if something you're trying isn't going to work on a certain API level.

Answer (score 0):

Java lambdas are supported by any Android API. Features like Streams or Functional Interfaces are supported in API 24+.

Here is the full list:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

AFAIK Android supports all features of Kotlin language.

Comment: I meant, Kotlin as special classes for collections etc that have monad methods integrated into them, are those available in previous levels ?

Comment: The question is about Kotlin though, and Kotlin streams and functional interfaces work well below 24.