# Is Kotlin as well supported as Java, for downstream users?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am deciding whether to use Kotlin or Java for an SDK project, and have some questions, all relating to downstream use of the SDK:

1. If I use Kotlin to build the SDK, will downstream users be able to use the resulting AAR in a Java-based project?
2. If I use Kotlin, will it affect what versions of Android the users of my AAR can target, compared to the equivalent Java code?
3. If I use Kotlin, will developers using older development environments (e.g. old versions of Android Studio) be forced to upgrade in order to build a project using my AAR?
4. Are there any other considerations that I may not have thought of which might prevent downstream users from being able to use my AAR if Kotlin is used, rather than Java?

## Background

We are about to embark on building an Android SDK to enable third-parties to interface with our project.

The consumable end result will be an AAR for third-party users to add into their projects.  This will provide both user-visible interfaces and developer APIs.  Developers can instantiate the UI class and have it do all the work for them (including user interactions) or they can use the developer API classes to build their own front-end from scratch.

We want our SDK to be as widely usable as possible, both in terms of supported Android versions/platforms and in terms of developer environments.

Would we limit our reach if we decided to develop the library using Kotlin, as opposed to Java, or are they fully interchangeable?  I am not clear about what dependencies Kotlin places on other developers (in terms of tool-chain) or on deployments (in terms of Android version support) and whilst there are lots of feature comparisons between the two languages, I haven't found anywhere that provides this kind of compatibility comparison.

---

**UPDATE:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539626/kotlin-on-android-is-there-a-minimum-api-level-requirement) indicates that there is no difference between them in terms of which Android API levels (i.e. which devices) they support.  Assuming this is the only consideration for Android compatibility, this seems like it answers question #2.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#is-kotlin-compatible-with-the-java-programming-language `Kotlin is 100% interoperable with the Java programming language and major emphasis has been placed on making sure that your existing codebase can interact properly with Kotlin. You can easily call Kotlin code from Java and Java code from Kotlin`

Comment: This is a very broad question, what research have you done so far and what exactly are your concerns? There are many resources available online you can consult regarding the differences between Java and Kotlin, especially the ones from Google and JetBrains.

Comment: @mowwwalker That is a good find.  That appears to answer the question about project support.  I'm also looking for information about toolchain, but what you've got there is a good basis for an answer!

Comment: @Egor I'm not sure why you think it's too broad, particularly given the first comment, which potentially offers most of an answer.  I'll be happy to refine it further if you give some pointers.  In terms of what research I have done - I have googled various phrases around the terms `java`, `kotlin`, `android`, `comparison` and `compatibility` but all the resources I've found so far focus on comparison of features.  I've not seen anything that compares compatibility.  This might be because there is no difference, or it might just be my poor Google foo.

Comment: @Egor This question was quick to be closed, but having rewritten it quite promptly, it seems to be very slow to be re-opened, or to receive any further feedback about any remaining issues.  How do I draw attention to this?

Comment: @HappyDog I voted to reopen. Although there are still multiple questions in one, which is [Stackoverflow's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for a question that needs more focus, they're closely related and a good answer should be able to cover all of them.

Comment: Thanks, @Egor, but it still needs more votes to re-open.  How do I get eyeballs on the updated question?  I feel like I've resolved the issues that caused it to be closed, but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to alert the original voters that it has now been changed, and no further feedback on the updated question has been given.  Would it be better to just repost it as a new question?

Comment: Yes, I think so. And just to reiterate, I suggest posting multiple questions if needed instead of a single post with multiple questions, as that would likely result in close votes as well. Stackoverflow works really well for focused questions where a short, non-opinionated answer can be provided.

Comment: _"will developers using older development environments (e.g. old versions of Android Studio)"_ How old is "old"? I believe I first started using kotlin in 2016, with whatever Android Studio version was available then. I've never tried using it with Eclipse or any other non-IDEA-based IDE.